# CSS linking issue

Tags: html, css

Currently having an issue using a .css file in combination with an html script. Currently my index.html looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Bellamy Terminal</title>

<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "../CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body class="css-theme">

<h1><strong>Bellamy Terminal</strong></h1>

</body>

</html>
```

To follow that up, in another directory/folder I have labeled CSS the following css script follows:

```
/* Theme of Site */
.css-theme {
    color: lime;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Typewriter;
}
/* Theme of Site End */

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The main issue is that my h1 element will not center which is a "wonderful" start for the beginning of my site lol. Would appreciate some help! Im using firefox

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/a04Lb3qe/

Comment: What you have is invalid. Missing `<head>` -- wrap `<style>` , `<link>`, and `<title>` elements in `<head>`...`</head>` and place `<title>` , `<link>`, and `<style>` in that order.

Comment: You said `h1` element is not being centered. Can you try adding `color: red` instead of text-align:center and let us know if it changes color of your h1 or not? This is to check if your css is actually being injected or not.

Comment: @TheUnKnown done. it did not change the color so it appears it is not being injected how can i fix that

Comment: @zer00ne did that and no change unfortunately :(

Comment: @CyberGuy Also `<link>` does not belong in `<style>` so your CSS file no matter where it is will ever work. Use the [TIDY] button the example looks atrocious.

Comment: Actually, if you change the code in the question all the time, your question and all answers and comments to it stop making sense...

Comment: Your [`doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Doctype) declaration is malformed, it should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`, note the position of the exclamation/bang character.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code in the question has now been edited multiple times by the OP which leads to the fact that most comments and answers don't make sense anymore.

Comment: @CyberGuy So you need to enter correct path. If you're having issues with it, move the css file to the same path where your html file is and just import it as: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `float: center;` - use `text-align: center` instead. And use `h1` in the selector, not `.h1` - that's not a class. So your complete rule is:

```
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And another note: You don't have a class called `css-theme` anywhere in your HTML code, so you can't expect that rule to be applied anywhere.

ADDITIONS:

1.) There might additionally be a filepath issue (in the link to the stylesheet), but without knowing your file structure it's impossible to give you exact instructions for that. You might try href = `../CSS/style.css` (note the two dots before the first slash), but that's just a guess.

2.) Your `<style>` and `<title>` tags should be wrapped in a `<head>` tag (which usually contains more than that), and the `<link>` tag should *not* be inside a `<style>` tag to make that valid HTML code.

Comment: same issue. it wont center, and if it helps at all the css is in a separate folder if that might tie into the issue

Comment: Then there's additionally a filepath issue (in the link to the stylesheet), but without knowing your file structure it's impossible to give you exact instructions for that. You might try `href = "../CSS/style.css"`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @CyberGuy , note the difference between a class selector and an element selector. Class has a `.` element does not

Comment: @JonP fixed. same issue still occurring

Comment: @Johannes yes you have the exact file directory right there so I'm going to conclude it's not a filepath issue :/

Comment: And another issue: Your `<style>` and `<title>` tags should be wrapped in a `<head>` tag. Concerning the filepath: Well - *you*  have a different one - try to change it.

Comment: @Johannes tried changing it and the above code is how I've changed it. Still no help

Comment: the `<link>` tag should not be inside a `<style>` tag

Comment: You might want to reread my answer once more since I summed up everything that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `doctype` should have the bang (`!`) before the word `doctype`.

Next, the `link` element does belong in the `head`, but not inside of `style`.

Also, while it's ok to add `class` to the `body` element, you can achieve the same result by setting up a CSS selector for `body` and eliminate the `class` from the HTML, which is generally preferred so that the HTML is less cluttered.

Additionally, [`strong`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong) is meant to convey importance semantically and usually causes the element it's used with to appear bolded. If all you are after is the bolding, `strong` isn't needed here because all heading elements will be bolded by default.

And, if you preface a relative URL with `/`, it will always look for the that resource at the root of your site, which may or may not be what you want. If the `CSS` folder is a child of the current page, don't preface the URL with `/`, just say the name of your folder as in: `CSS/style.css`.

```css
/* Theme of Site */
/* If you make a tag selector, you don't have to add a class to the element */
body {
    color: lime;
    background-color: black;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Typewriter;
}
/* Theme of Site End */

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bellamy Terminal</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/CSS/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bellamy Terminal</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```